# Are these components connected correctly?

Tags: sensors

I intend to use two ultrasonic sensors as input and a vibration motor as its output, is this connected correctly?

[image]

As part of my project, I intend to use an ultrasonic sensor to feed in distance data and react through vibration motor. I have to confirm this arrangement will work but I don't own an Arduino.

Comment: That diagram is a case in point for why Fritzing should never be used for anything, ever. It really doesn't help people to learn how to do a proper schematic, and when people do use it the results are so meaningless as to be laughable.

Answer (score 2):

in short: Definitely Not.

1 : you do really need to connect the trigger pins of the ultrassonic sensors, or else you will not be able to "trigger" them.
Read the ultrassound library examples, they may help you.

2 : I am pretty sure an analog (or digital for that matter) pin in arduino nano cannot sink the current needed to make the motor spin. You are going to fry that pin/port or even brick the entire arduino.
Read on power mosfets for the solution of that.

Moreover, i don't think the 5v out of the arduino feeding the motor is a good idea as well, as the current given by its internal regulator may not be enough for the motor as well.

Comment: Yep, unless it is a 20 mA motor, you need an alternative arrangement. Also, driving the whole thing from a 9V battery is a doubtful proposition. You may also want a snubber diode over the motor pins.

Comment: @ Marcus Thanks for replying. The trig pins are definitely connected to the board, just that when using this software(fritzing), I won't be able drag the wire to trig pin (it will relocated to the centre), I don't know whether it is a bug or not.

Comment: Regarding the vibration motor, I took reference from [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Vibrating-Distance-Sensor/?ALLSTEPS), I just wonder why it will work for that. Here is the schematics for my reference [link](http://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/F6F/1E9M/IBC294QB/F6F1E9MIBC294QB.pdf)